# How do i get dolphin on my raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, retropie, emulation

I have a raspberry pi 3 with retropie and have been trying to get dolphin (emulator) on it, and have failed numerous times.
is there any way to install dolphin on my pi?

Comment: You can manually install it with `dpkg` command. Find your fitted package [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dolphin).

Comment: Would that work with retropie?
And also are there any videos showing how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In what way did the following fail?

```
sudo apt install dolphin
```

Comment: ok i just did that (all the other methods showed much more complicated methods) could i get it on retropie?

Comment: I have no idea.  If retropie is based on Raspbian then the same command should work.

Comment: ok thanks for your assistance anyways

Comment: `sudo apt install dolphin` I just did this (it installed a lot of dependencies!), it worked fine, but I have to say I don't like Dolphin as much as xfe or pcmanfm